# MVC4 model change will not reflect in subsequent Page calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been researching for several hours in an attempt to find a solution, no other SO entry  or other source's entry seems to have addressed this specific issue. What is presented is an extremely scaled down version of the actual code, but it demonstrates the problem completely, and if this issue can be corrected, the larger code will be fixed as well. The problem is this:

MVC4

Index page on a Home controller, one HttpPost action and one HttpGet action

Simple Model called PassModel one property called A (string)

An Html DisplayFor on that single field in the @foreach loop

An HTML item that can be clicked that calls a jQuery function

On load, the page presents the letter "A" and an input element.  The "A" is loaded into the single field in the view model.

on click of the input element, a jQuery function is called.

it submits an ajax POST which properly calls the Index action with the appropriate data ( "C" ) , which is loaded back into a view model instance.

Debug walk shows that the model is completely changed with the jQuery passed value "C", and the changed model has value "C" heading into the View

When return View(model) occurs, the old value of "A" is still displayed, the newly inserted value into the model is ignored ( "C" )

Is it possible in the structure supplied for the changed model contents to be displayed in the second pass into the View?  I have tried many suggestions on the web that were somewhat similar to what I am experiencing, have changed post to get, switched to $.get and $.post instead (with the appropriate annotation change), Model.State.Clear(), all to no avail.

Appreciate any suggestions ...  the entire code involved is shown below

Code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string id) {
        IList<PassModel> b = new List<PassModel>();
        PassModel x = new PassModel();
        x.A = id;
        b.Add(x);
        return View("Index", b);
    }    
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var x = new PassModel();
        x.A = "A";
        IList<PassModel> a = new List<PassModel>();
        a.Add(x);
        return View("Index",a);
    }
}

function fill(object) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Index',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { id: "C" },
    })

}

@model IList<PassModel>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value="Input" onclick="fill(this)"/>

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JavaScript1.js"></script>


public class PassModel {
    public string A { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You making an ajax call. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. You post to the `Index()` method which returns a View (it should be a partial view), but you never do anything with that view - ie. update the DOM. Add a `<div id="content"></div>` element in the view, and then in the ajax add `success: function(data) { $('#content').html(data); }` to understand how it works (although in reality you would return a partial view of the table, and only update the table)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Appears to be a misunderstanding on my part how MVC/helpers helpers could solve my requirement. goal is to provide a screen that has a dropdown list of dates that are keys to sets of data in a database.  Screen first displays with the top 1 date from a series of dates, and the data extracted from EF populates the model, which is sent to the View. Works great.  When date changed in the dropdown, I would just refresh the Model with the returned data, and let the helpers map it into the page.  I guess it doesn't work that way so I'll need to rethink how to do this.

Comment: Further, your reply made me consider how this was being approached. I changed tactics and moved my selection list off the page I was refreshing.  Now with a foreach populating the dates' list with an ActionLink per date, I now could pass the needed value to the ActionMethod.  From there it was easy now to submit different values into this processing chain, and I was able to achieve what I needed without having a javascript onchange event tied on the DropDownList.  Thanks again.